# Checking an empty object array in C#

Tags: c#

I have the following code in my application:

```
SqlParameter[] sqlCmdParameters=new SqlParameter[0];
```

Later, I am passing the array to a method as following:

```
 void CallDB( SqlParameter[] sqlCmdParameters)
 {

       if (sqlCmdParameters == null && sqlCmdParameters.Length>=0 )
       {
           return;
       }   
       Console.Writeline(sqlCmdParameters[0].value);        

  }
```

The above code encounters an "Object reference not found exception"  as the array is empty.
I could perform a element wise null checking in the loop but I think that would not be a good approach.
What is the best practice to check for empty array in C#? Also, why an empty array length is 1 when there is no element at all?

Comment: please check my answer and tell me if the bug is gone.

Answer (score 2):

You should change your if statment

```
 if (sqlCmdParameters == null || sqlCmdParameters.Length == 0 )
 {
      return;
 }
```

In your case you can't never hit the return, because parameters cannot be null and their Length = 0.

Here you have List of SqlParameters.

```
List<SqlParameter> sqlCmdParameters= new List<SqlParameter>();
SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
param.Value = "test";
sqlCmdParameters.Add(param);
```

If you choose to use List you should check in the if statement

```
 if (sqlCmdParameters == null || sqlCmdParameters.Count == 0 )
 {
      return;
 }
```

Comment: If u just declare a array by the statement

Answer (score 0):

Your Code seems to be not proper.

It should be like this.

```
SqlParameter[] sqlCmdParameters=new SqlParameter[0];    

 void CallDB( SqlParameter[] sqlCmdParameters)
 {

       if (sqlCmdParameters == null || sqlCmdParameters.Length <= 0 )
       {
           return;
       }   
       Console.Writeline(sqlCmdParameters[0].value);        

  }
```